# How to send an event to gtag?

Tags: google-analytics, eventhandler, gtag.js

I can’t catch the target with the event type, the rest of the targets (via the transition link) work successfully

doing so

Goal Setting -> Own

Target Description -> Event

Target Details ->
Category equals custom
Action equals add_2_order

here
[image]

In the code I do it and does not work:

```
gtag('event', 'add_2_order', {'event_category':'custom'});
```

still did and still doesn't work

```
gtag('event', 'my_add_2_order', {'event_category':'custom','event_action':'add_2_order'});
```

still true .. what am I doing wrong and where to look?
gtag in the head is inserted, but not a single event target works and all goals work if they hit the page

Answer (score 0):

This is the right code:

```
gtag('event', 'add_2_order', { 'event_category': 'custom' });
```

If it doesn't work it means that something is blocking the event and you can't find it in the event report either.